# Yum update error on RedHat 5

Tags: rhel, yum

since one of our guys tried installing Dell OpenManage on our RedHat server we have been getting this error when trying to update it:

```
    # yum update
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, rhnplugin, security
http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/OMSA_5.4//mirrors.pl?osname=el5&basearch=x86_64&repo_config=$repo_config&dellsysidpluginver=$dellsysidpluginver
using mirror: http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/OMSA_5.4/platform_independent/rh50_64
This system is receiving updates from ULN.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 157, in main
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 187, in getOptionsConfig
    self.conf
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 668, in <lambda>
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 254, in _getConfig
    self.plugins.run('init')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 179, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/rhnplugin.py", line 175, in init_hook
    repo = RhnRepo(channel)
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/rhnplugin.py", line 339, in __init__
    self.gpgkey = get_gpg_key_urls(channel['gpg_key_url'])
  File "/usr/share/rhn/up2date_client/rhnChannel.py", line 48, in __getitem__
    return self.dict[item]
KeyError: 'gpg_key_url'
```

Any ideas?

I have tried pretty much all error solutions I have come across.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the dellsysid plugin is conflicting with the rhnplugin.
Depending on which channels you wish to use one of them will likely need to be disabled.

In case you don't know which one to use:
There is an option to tell yum not to load a plugin. Try running with one of these two disabled to see which one gives you the expected packages.